# Integrateing openfeint in xcode using unity3d

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, openfeint

I want to make an `openfeint` leaderboard in `xcode` using Unity3d.

I am using Unity 3.2 and openfeint 2.9.1.

I have built correctly as well as what they told in openfeint Unity support readme.txt and open feint web link.

But I'm getting error like

> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

**What am I doing wrong?**

I'm working with ios 4.2.

I have tried and corrected well all unity player settings and set the target ios platform from `3.0` to `3.2` but I am getting the same error.

Can any one point out what am doing wrong.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy but took time as it happens :)

In `Editor\OpenFeint\XCode\Appcontroller+OpenFeint.mm` You must remove `UnitySetAudioSessionActive()` in the methods `dashboardDidDisappear()` and `dashboardWillDisappear()`.

And everything becomes OK. Don't understand why it is there at all when `UnityPause()` is there?

UPDATED: You must remove `UnitySetAudioSessionActive()` ONLY in the methods `dashboardWillAppear()` and `dashboardDidDisappear()` (or sound will stop playing after disabling device there...

by that I thought you will get out from your OpenFeint Problem ..

Vivek Shah